# Facebook Graph API ad Insights not showing all data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to use Facebook Graph API to request some data in my job, im using the Graph Explorer from Facebook to test with the following request

```
v18.0\<AD_SET_ID\>/insights
```

With this request im only getting

```
account_id 
campaign_id
adset_id
date_start
date_stop
impressions
spend
```

The fields that i need is mainly conversions, but even when i specify to show only conversions, it appears as it doesn't even exist

Is there a way to get the missing data?

I already tried to use campaign_id and ad_id instead of the ad_set_id to get the insights but i got the same problem with missing data

I also gave the access token all possible permissions to check if it was a lack of permissions issue, but the problem persisted.